# Choosing Projected CRS for Uganda

Tags: coordinate-system, africa, uganda

I'm curious to know what the correct projected CRS for Uganda is and if there is a national grid?

Is it ok to use UTM as it is conformal?

Comment: It depends on the size of your area and what coordinate system your source/reference features are in and *how* you want to use the data. Projected reference systems can give real metrics on length and area but taking a bearing isn't going to end well over a long distance, UTM zones are 6 degrees wide, going further than that Albers or Lamberts might be more suitable.. all that aside, if your data is based on the WGS84 datum Google Mercator (EPSG:3857) or, as Uganda only encroaches on zone 35 by a tiny amount and is approximately 3/4 above the Equator WGS84 UTM Zone 36 North might suit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not authoritative, but at a [government open data page](http://catalog.data.ug/dataset/artisanal-mining-locations-in-uganda/resource/06310474-3524-4e39-92a5-49fb2e322714)  they provide location data as both UTM coordinates and WGS84 coordinates. Exactly what UTM CRS that is is not stated, or I could not find it.

Comment: Transforming a random selection of a dozen coordinates using https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=32636&t_srs=4326 shows anecdotally that the eastings and northings on that page are WGS84 UTM Zone 36 North, as such you could conclude that EPSG:32626 is in use for authoritative data within Uganda. Nice find!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks guys!

Comment: Utm in uganda is probably based on the Arc1960 datum see Mugnier on Uganda: https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/08-2012-Uganda.pdf